# Firefox 4.0 does not show type to be "application/xhtml+xml"

Tags: html, firefox, xhtml, mime-types

I have the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js" type="javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in Firefox 4.0, click on Tools > Page info, it always shows the Type="text/html". Does this mean the the document is being served with the MIME type of text/plain. If so, how do I serve it with the MIME Type of application/xhtml+xml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the document was served with the MIME type of `text/html`.

To serve it with the MIME Type of `application/xhtml+xml` you will need to configure your web server to do so.

Comment: Dear Oded, Kindly forgive my ignorance. I was not asking for "content Negotation". This is done from the client side. The file is on a hard disk. Should I save the file as .xhtml?

Comment: @JAA149 - You could, but you would then need to associate the correct mime type to the .xhtml extension (how this is done depends on your OS).

Comment: I am not sure why this does not work. It has too. I read it in a book. Although I don't remmber the book. The author uses the same exact code as above and than leaves out the closing tag of </p>. This causes the browser to give the yellow screen of death error. This in turn means that the document is being parased with the XML paraser as agnaist to the HTML paraser and this in turn again means that the document is being served with application/xhtml. I am sure I am doing something wrong. But What?

Comment: @JAA149 - You're quite close. If you load a local file (i.e. the url uses the `file:` scheme) with a .xhtml extension into Firefox 4 on Windows, it should use the XML parser. This does not automatically apply when the page is served by a web server - as Oded says, the server will need to be configured to do so.

Comment: Thanks Alohci. Yes it worked. I changed the file extension from .html to .xhtml and loaded it in Firefox 4.0 in Windows. Now that Page Info > type states it to be of the type "application/xhtml+xml". Additionally I deleted the cloosing </p> tag and it gave me the Yellow Screen of Death. However IE9 still displays it normally which means it is not being served with application/xhtml

Comment: and the XML paraser is not being used. Does this mean IE9 does not support the MIME Type applications/xhtml+xml. I tried this with a live site on www.codeslinger.info but the whole xml decalration is not there despite my putting it there and uploading. I am new to Web Development and am in my 3rd week, so dont mind my stupid questions. Do I have to request my hosting company to provide support for this. Thanks

Comment: @JAA149 - Be careful about your test. IE9 in application/xhtml+xml mode does not show YSODs. It shows the parsed page up to the point where it first detects a XML well-formedness error, and then nothing else. Both that and the YSOD are compatible with the XML specification, which simply says that XML parsers must stop parsing when they hit a well-formedness error.

Comment: @JAA149 - "Do I have to request my hosting company to provide support for this." Possibly, it depends on the hosting company. If you're using a server side language like PHP, you can also set the content type header in your PHP code.

Comment: Alochi Said: "It shows the parsed page up to the point where it first detects a XML well-formedness error, and then nothing else". However this is not working. I changed my code as "<p>this is a paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 1
<p>another</p>". You will notice that the <h1> element does not have an ending tag. IE9 shows all of these tags as if nothing is wrong. Mybe it is not using the XML paraser. How do I use the XML paraser?

Comment: @JAA149 - That's what I mean about being careful about your test. The XML well-formedness error won't be detected until it becomes certain that the `</h1>` tag isn't there, which won't be until the end of your test string. Had you written `<p>this is a paragraph</p> <h1>Heading 1 </div><p>another</p>`, then the well-formedness error would have been detected at the `</div>` tag and the `<p>another</p>` would not be displayed.